# ASP.NET MVC 3 Client side method to show or hide a field based on the value of a related field using attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For my model I require an attribute somewhat like the following:

```
[Required (ErrorMessage = "Please select yes or no")]
public bool IsAlien {get; set; }

[ConditionalDisplayIfTrue ("IsAlien ")]
public string NameOfGalaxy {get; set;}
```

And then show or hide the text box client side if IsAlien is selected.

Is's very easy to hardwire it in jQuery/Jvascript but I would like to do this *properly* and have no idea where to start.

By properly I mean to add custom attributes and custom JavaScript to hook up with unobtrusive JavaScript validation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing this via jQuery/Javascript *is* the proper way to do it. Any C# library you use is going to generate the requisite javascript on the server and send it back to the browser for you. I don't know any library that supports this right now, but for something so simple would prefer to have control over my javascript than use somebody elses.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have expanded the question. I am expecting to write JavaScript but want to link it in to C# attributes and the unobtrusive libraries

Comment: Still researching and may post a solution one day but best to close this for now.